In MS Word, in a long block of text, how can I replace every instance of string "<any digit>space" with "<the same digit>paragraph mark"?
The heading says it all: In MS Word, in a long block of text, how can I replace every instance of string "space" with "paragraph mark"?
I have a large block of text, within which are time stamps in the form "hh.mm.ss" (which incidentally are also hyperlinks) preceded by a colon and a space ": ".  These are followed by a single space, after which is another string of text (which contains spaces, but no digits), followed by the next colon, space, time stamp.
I want to either replace the space after the time stamps with a Paragraph mark, or add one after it - doesn't matter which.
The problem is putting the digit from the space back again in the Replace string.

You can use regular expressions for identifying timestamps. Open Find and Replace dialog window and click on More. Check "Use wildcards", which allows you to use regular expressions.
For your particular case, inside "Find what" use the following expression:
([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})

which detects timestamp with format "hh.mm.ss". It assumes that all your timestamps are correctly defined, as it also detects impossible values, such as 99.99.99.
Inside "Replace with" insert:
\1^13

where "\1" repeats found timestamp; "^13" inserts a paragraph mark.
This method inserts a paragraph mark, while retaining space after each timestamp
